# Automatic model migrations in Vapor 4/Fluent still exist?

Tags: vapor, vapor-fluent

I'm trying to follow the upgrade guide to Vapor 4 with my Vapor 3 project. I have used the Vapor 3 automatic model migrations a lot. But going through the Vapor 4 upgrade guide, they aren't mentioned anymore, in fact they use specific migrations for every model. So, don't they exist anymore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there are two options (credits to @vzsg)

> - you can pass an `--auto-migrate` parameter to the process (swift run Run serve --auto-migrate in the command line, and via Edit Scheme in Xcode)
> - you can manually call and wait for migrations `try app.autoMigrate().wait()`

Comment: Thanks for help!